# Splitting large angular module into multiple modules inside AEM project using webpack and gulp

Tags: angular, webpack, gulp, aem

I have one large angular module inside my AEM project. My project is not entirely an angular project -- it is more of an "angular on demand" project. I compile the angular project using webpack and gulp. I am trying to split my large angular module into separate smaller modules. I can do this successfully and have the project compile and build, but when I navigate to pages containing those angular components that I have moved into my new module, they don't show up on the page.

My folder structure is as follows:

- app

  - dist
  - node_modules
  - src

    - component1
    - component2
    - component3
    - component4
    - component5
    - newModule

      - component6
      - component7
      - component8
      - newModule.module.ts
    - app.module.ts
    - main.ts
    - polyfills.ts
- index.html
- webpack.config.js
- gulpfile.js
- gulpfile.json

in my webpack.config.js I'm not sure how many entry points I should now have... should I have one more my newModule that is pointing to my newModule.module.ts or just one that is pointing to my main.ts file? I just cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm missing to not have my components load on the page!!!

newModule.module.ts file :

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef, Injectable, Inject, 
ComponentFactoryResolver, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {component6} from './component6/component6.component';
import {component7} from './component7/component7.component';
import {component8} from './component8/component8.component';
import {component6service} from './component6/component6.service';
import {component7service} from './component7/component7.service';



@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
  declarations: [
      component6,
      component7,
      component8
  ],
    providers: [
       component6service,
       component7service,
    ],
exports: [
  component6,
  component7,
  component8
]
})
export class newModule { }
```

app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef, Injectable, Inject, 
ComponentFactoryResolver, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { newModule } from './newModule/newModule.module';
import {component1} from './component1/component1.component';
import {component2} from './component2/component2.component';
import {component3} from './component3/component3.component';
import {component4} from './component4/component4.component';
import {component5} from './component5/component5.component';
import {component1service} from './component1/component1.service';
import {component3service} from './component3/component3.service';

const mainComponents: Array<any> = [
    component1,
    component2,
    component3,
    component4,
    component5
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        component1,
        component2,
        component3,
        component4,
        component5
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        newModule
    ],
    entryComponents: mainComponents,
    exports: [
        newModule
     ],
    providers: [
        component1service,
        component3service
     ]
})
@Injectable()
export class AppModule {

 factoryResolver: any;
    initialize: Boolean = true;
    isInitialized: Boolean = false;

constructor(@Inject(ComponentFactoryResolver) factoryResolver, private _appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
    this.factoryResolver = factoryResolver;
}

ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {

    this.initialize = (this.initialize);

    if(this.initialize) {
       this.isInitialized == false && this._initAngular(appRef);
    }else {
       this._appConfigService.userInfoRefresh.subscribe((data) => {
            if(data == 'initAngular') {
               this.isInitialized == false && this._initAngular(appRef);
            }

            ;
       });
    }
}

private _initAngular(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    this.isInitialized = true;
    mainComponents.forEach((componentDef: Type<{}>) => {
        const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentDef);
        const elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(factory.selector));
        const selectorName = factory.selector;

        if (elements.length === 0)
            return;
        else {
            elements.forEach((element, i) => {
                element.id = selectorName + '_' + i;
                (<any>factory).factory.selector = '#' + element.id;
                appRef.bootstrap(factory);
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

main.ts file:

```
 import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";
 import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser- 
 dynamic";
 import {AppModule} from "./app.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => 
console.log(err));
```

Comment: I resolved this but not sure if it was the correct way or a work around ... I ended up importing all components from other modules into app.module.ts like so: 

import {component4} from './../newmodule/component4/component4.component';

and then adding them to 'mainComponents' array. This allowed them to get bootstrapped via the function on the bottom. not sure why this doesnt work when i add the same function to the bottom newModule.module.ts file but alas